# Certain image links resulting in corrupt downloads when using requests with shutil/f.write

Tags: python, file-io, python-requests, shutil

I've noticed that when I try to download different images,
certain images are ending up corrupt despite being valid image links.
I've used shutil and f.write(context manager) to write images to a file, and I've notice that depending on which one of those I use, different images tend to get corrupt.

Here is one such image link that gets corrupted when using **shutil**:

'http://www.floridagofishing.com/_images/fish/bonito-atlantic.JPG'

Here is a sample of the code I was using (made some changes to fit this single example, so hopefully there aren't any unintentional errors)

```
      import shutil
      import requests
      from fake_useragent import UserAgent
      ua = UserAgent()
      headers = {'User-Agent': ua.firefox}

       try:
       r = requests.get(link, stream=True, headers = headers)

     except (requests.exceptions.RequestException) as e:
        print(e)
        continue

        with open('testing' + '.jpg', 'wb') as f:
                 shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
                 print('image downloaded')
```

If I use f.write in this case, it works but f.write
 produces different corrupted images such as this link:

```
 'https://journal.amberjack.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/pmack-e1473782709607.png'   #valid image file

       try:
           r = requests.get(link, headers = headers)

      except (requests.exceptions.RequestException) as e:
         print(e)
         continue

        with open('testing' + '.' + 'jpg', 'wb') as f:
                 f.write(r.content)
                 print('image downloaded: Total =  ', image_count)
```

This is resulting in a corrupt image.

What exactly is going on and how can I avoid the corruption of images?

Thank you.